# How to add scripts to bloggers thumbnail image infinite scroll plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger, infinite-scroll

everyone,
I have trouble the script to add an image thumbnail in blogger. the following script:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  function bp_thumbnail_resize(image_url,post_title) {
    var image_size=300;
    var show_default_thumbnail=true;
    var default_thumbnail="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-4fqrt2MACHQ/UADPlJjibiI/AAAAAAAAAcc/FBN03q3jT2A/s1600/blank_post_thumbnail.png";
    if(show_default_thumbnail == true && image_url == "") image_url= default_thumbnail;
    image_tag='<img src="'+image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/s'+image_size+'-c/')+'" class="postthumb" alt="'+post_title+'"/>';
    yimage_tag = '<img src="' + image_url.replace('default', '0') + '" alt="' + post_title + '"/>';
    if (image_url.indexOf("img.youtube.com")!= -1){
      return yimage_tag;
    }
    else if (image_url != "") {
      return image_tag;
    }
    else
    return "";
  }
  //]]>
    </script>
```

to call it:

```
document.write(bp_thumbnail_resize(&quot;<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>&quot;,&quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;));
```

and I want to use the infinite scroll plugin with the code here:

[Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/manki-scripts/source/browse/blogger-infinite-scrolling.js)

I've tried to edit the code but it still does not work, i please ask for your help. Thank you.

Comment: Even i had tons of issues with the infinite scroll plugin.I failed in the end.Have a look at this http://www.thesimplexdesign.com/2013/02/infinite-scrolling-or-load-more-effect.html

Comment: @Michel Thank you, share links to the article and I will try it.